# Does flock understand && command for multiple bash commands?

Tags: bash, flock

I am using bash and flock on centos.

Normally I would run `cd /to/my/dir && python3.6 runcommand.py`

But then we add it to cron and don't want output so add `> /dev/null 2>&1`

And add a flock before it to prevent multiple instances, like so:

```
flock -n ~/.my.lock cd /to/my/dir && python3.6 runcommand.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Question**
Only does this flock the `cd /to/my/dir` and then execute the `python3.6` (normally without flock) or does it flock the complete row of bash commands (so both) and only unlock when `python3.6 runcommand.py` is also finished?

Not clear from the man and examples I found.

Comment: `&&` is a shell construct, so `flock` isn't aware of it.

Comment: `flock` isn't even *given* your whole command by the shell -- it can't "understand" or "support" something it never even sees. All it gets is `flock -n ~/.my.lock cd /to/my/dir` (with the `~` already replaced with the actual directory name); nothing else is even visible to it.

Comment: (None of that is in any respect specific to `flock` -- if you were running, say, `echo cd /to/my/dir && python3.6 runcommand.py`, then `echo` too would only be given the single command before the `&&`).

Comment: (To be a bit more pedantically correct: What `flock` gets is an argument vector that looks like this: `char*[]{"flock", "-n", "/home/whatever/.my.lock", "cd", "/to/my/dir", NUL}` -- ie. it doesn't even get the original string, but an array of separate C strings that the shell creates when parsing the command line).

Comment: Suggestion: don't add logic to the crontab.  Write a script with the logic and invoke the script.  Crontabs should be absolutely trivial, IMO without even any redirections.  But the redirections in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell interprets your command this way:

```
flock -n ~/.my.lock cd /to/my/dir && python3.6 runcommand.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

- Step 1: Run `flock -n ~/.my.lock cd /to/my/dir` part
- Step 2: If the command in step 1 exits with non-zero, skip step 3
- Step 3: Run `python3.6 runcommand.py > /dev/null 2>&1` part

So, `flock` has no business with `&&` or the right side of it.

You could do this instead:

```
touch ./.my.lock # no need for this step if the file is already there and there is a potential that some other process could lock it
(
  flock -e 10
  cd /to/my/dir && python3.6 runcommand.py > /dev/null 2>&1
) 10< ./.my.lock
```

---

See this post on Unix & Linux site:

- [How to use flock and file descriptors to lock a file and write to the locked file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184259/can-someone-explain-how-to-use-flock-and-file-descriptors-to-lock-a-file-and-wri)

Comment: `(cd /to/my/dir && exec flock -n ~/.my.lock python 3.6 runcommand.py >/dev/null 2>&1)` would also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in **crontab**. Here is my way -

```
*/30 * * * * cd /home/myfolder/ /usr/bin/flock -w 0 /home/myfolder/my-file.lock && python my_script.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```